# Java Turkish Character

Tags: java, encoding, xls

```
String filename = "c:/book.xls";
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
ws.setLocale(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
try {
   Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filename),ws);
   //......................
}
```

I am trying to read Xls file in Turkish. I set locale to Turkish. However, it still doesn't show Turkish characters. Can you help me out?

Comment: Do you know what enconding the file uses?

Comment: Encode the file in UTF-8: http://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-software-support/tutorials/getting-started/how-to-encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was about my Java IDE(Eclipse) encoding problem, I changed it by saving as UTF-8 and It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Set the encoding used in this the workbook:

Try

```
ws.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

or

```
ws.setEncoding("ISO8859_9")
```

or

```
ws.setEncoding("ISO-8859-9")
```